# Update collection with WhereIn statment with their relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have code updating a collection as follows

```php
    Transaction::whereIn('id', $inProcessIds)
        ->update([
            'transfer_status' => SaleTransaction::TRANSFER_STATUS_TRANSFERRED
        ]);
```

In Transaction I have relation to another model

```php
    public function sale_offer() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\SaleOffer', 'sale_offer_id', 'id');
    }
```

What I want to do is update related model at once when I updating Transaction

Here's what I tried to do is

```php
    Transaction::whereIn('id', $inProcessIds)->with('sale_offer')
        ->update([
            'transfer_status' => SaleTransaction::TRANSFER_STATUS_TRANSFERRED
            'transaction.sale_offer => 1'
        ]);
```

or

```php
    Transaction::whereIn('id', $inProcessIds)->sale_offer()
        ->update([
            'transfer_status' => SaleTransaction::TRANSFER_STATUS_TRANSFERRED
            'transaction.sale_offer => 1'
        ]);
    ]);
```

Comment: what is column you are trying to update on sale_offer table ?

Comment: @AhmedAtoui OMG, Of course I forgot about column which I want to update. I want to update column amount_sent in SaleOffer table

Answer (score 0):

You can update related model by extract **sale_offers** ids from **Transaction** table  then update sale_offer :

```
  $sale_offer_ids=Transaction::whereIn('id', $inProcessIds)->with('sale_offer')->pluck('sale_offer_id')->toArray();
```

then update sale offer :

```
  SaleOffer::whereIn('id',$sale_offer_ids)->update(['amount_sent'=>$amount_sent]) ;
```